# How can I print only last few list in the emulator in list view widget? I have the list below for rest API

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I want to show  the  last 5 list in list view, I am able to do this for 1st 5 list but not for last 5. How can I get the last 5 list in my emulator.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; 
import 'package:http/http.dart'; 
import 'package:restapipro/models/posts.dart'; 
import 'package:restapipro/services/remote_service.dart'; 

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget { 
const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key); 

@override 
State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState(); 
} 

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> { 
   List<Post>? posts; 
   var isLoaded = false; 
   var reverse=false; 

@override 
void initState() { 
   super.initState(); 
  //fetch data from API 
  getData(); 
} 

Future getData() async { 
       posts = await RemoteService().getPosts(); 
          if (posts != null) { 
              setState(() { 
                    isLoaded = true; 
              }); 
        } 
  } 

 @override 
 Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
 return Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Posts'),), 
 body: Visibility(visible: isLoaded, 
 replacement: const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),), 
 child: ListView.builder(reverse: true,itemCount: 5, 
 itemBuilder: (context, index) { 
 return Container(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16), 
 child: Row(children: [Container(height: 50,width: 50, 
 decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12), 
 color: Colors.grey[300],),), 
 const SizedBox(width: 16), 
 Expanded(child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, 
          children: [Text(posts![index].title, maxLines: 2,overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, 
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),), 
          Text(posts![index].body ?? '', 
               maxLines: 3,
               overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,)
               ,],),),]),); 
       }),),); 
    } 
  }
```

I just want to know how can I get the widget to print last 5 list from n number of list.

Comment: you can reverse the initial list that you get from API and show the first 5 after reversal. use `<ListObject>.reverse.toList().sublist(0,5)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm only answering what I understood from your question as the block of code seems messy. I suppose you only want to render last 5 items of your List that you got from API and I also suppose you only need to render those last 5 items ignoring the other.

Taking above condition in mind, let's keep only the last 5 items of the fetched lists into your `post` variable.

For this, change your `getPosts`() function to this:

```
Future getPosts() async{

    List<Post>? fetchedPosts = await RemoteService().getPosts();
    if(fetchedPosts != null){
      posts = fetchedPosts.where((e) => (fetchedPosts.length - fetchedPosts.indexOf(e)) <= 5 ).toList();
       setState((){
         isLoaded = true;
         });
       }
   }
```

This'll set last 5 items of the list in `post` if the length of list is greater than 5, and will add all the items in the `post` list if the length is lesser.

Implement this in your function and you're good to go.